# Parsing the URL with regex on Ruby to find the word in between known start and end or no end

Tags: ruby, regex

I try the get spreadsheet's key value e.g. "**0ApdtEzo-JYQ4dFdMd3drb2VKX0tKaT2o1WVhDX1**". URL looks like this

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApdtEzo-JYQ4dFdMd3drb2VKX0tKaT2o1WVhDX1E#gid=0
```

or

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApdtEzo-JYQ4dFdMd3drb2VKX0tKaT2o1WVhDX1E
```

Only manage to get the portion including the "key=" and "#" on this workbench: http://rubular.com/r/pBTIj6LgeN

I'd appreciate any suggestion since it took my more than 1 hour already

Comment: Rather than parsing the URL yourself, use the [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this pattern, which do not require the ending `#`:

```
(?<=key\=)([^#]+)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the word "key=" shouldn't be in the result

Comment: @baris Sorry it needed a negative look-behind. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes I came up to this answer by combining your previous answer with @halfelf

Answer (score 1):

How about `/(?<=key=).*(?=#gid)/` , if you don't want `key=` and `#...`

Comment: I combined your answer with @Sina Iravanian : (?<=key=)([^#]+)